# Add Field level security for person accounts field

Tags: permissions, standard-objects, person-accounts, field-level-security

Good day everyone, I am trying to add a field level security to first name, last name field for a person account. What I did is that I go to the user profile and I've tried to update the field level security of account but I didn't find the first name and last name field. I also tried to go to contact and update it's field level security but I still didn't find first name and last in there. What am I missing ? What is the remedy I can do for my problem ? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name is a compound field on these two objects. Which is a combination of FirstName, Lastname, Salutation. You can't set security for individual field. You need to setup this for Name field.

BTW Name is a required field so I don't think you can hide it from user if you are allowing them to create record.

Comment: Thank you so much mate this is very useful. One question that I forgot to include, I also want to find the field level security for user object like username and email but i didn't find it. Do you know where I can set the field level security for that ?

Comment: @Hope SF doesn't allow some native fields on user to be hidden. Not quite sure but maybe email, username is one of them.